# How to detect blur event on an input field whose name attribute is known in meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

In the template, I have many input fields and each of the field is assigned a name attribute as shown below:

```
 <input name="n1" type="number">
 <input name="n2" type="number">
 <input name="n3" type="number">
```

The goal is to detect blur event on input field whose name is n1. I have written following code for it, which detects blur on all the input fields:

```
'blur':function(event,template){
        event.preventDefault();
        var value = $(event.target).val();
        console.log(value);
    }
```

How can I write blur event specifically for n1 input field?

Comment: in the return 'event' var, why cant you find the name of element whether it is n1 and then write the func? Otherwise, could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: `'blur input[name="n1"]': function(event,template)`